# Python pandas not importing values as is on Oracle

Tags: python, oracle, scripting, spyder, cx-oracle

I imported a txt file on my python script and then converted it to dataframe. Then I created a function that uses cx_oracle to insert my data to Oracle database faster. It works pretty well and it only took 15min to import 1mil+ data - but it doesn't copy the values as is. This is a chunk of that code:

```
sqlquery = 'INSERT INTO {} VALUES({})'.format(tablename, inserttext)
df_list = df.values.tolist()
cur = con.cursor()

cur.execute(sql_query1)
logger.info("Completed: %s", sql_query1)

for b in df_list :

    for index, value in enumerate(b):
        if isinstance(value, float) and math.isnan(value):
            b[index] = None
        elif isinstance(value, type(pd.NaT)):
            b[index] = None
```

Here is a sample data of what I expected:

| DATE | STORE | COST | PARTIAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 16-JUN-21 08.00.00.000000000 PM | 00006 | +00000.0082 | false |

But instead this is being imported

| DATE | STORE | COST | PARTIAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 16-JUN-21 | 6 | 0.0082 | F |

I need it to be eaxcatly same with zeros, symbols etc. I've already tried converting the dataframe as string by doing `df = df.astype(str)` but it doesn't work.

Hopefully you can help!

Comment: I suggest that prior to import change the columns data types on your table to string, because python makes asumptions on data types.

Comment: If you want to store strings, make all of your Oracle database column types VARCHAR2.

Comment: Yes all the columns are in string, which is why I'm also not sure why it's not just taking the format I import.

Answer (score 1):

Without going into whether the schema design and architecture is really what you should be using, then with this schema:

```
create table t (d varchar2(31), s varchar2(6), c varchar(12), p varchar(5));
```

and this data in `t.csv`:

```
16-JUN-21 08.00.00.000000000 PM,00006,+00000.0082,false
```

and this code:

```
import cx_Oracle
import os
import sys
import csv

if sys.platform.startswith("darwin"):
    cx_Oracle.init_oracle_client(lib_dir=os.environ.get("HOME")+"/Downloads/instantclient_19_8")

username = os.environ.get("PYTHON_USERNAME")
password = os.environ.get("PYTHON_PASSWORD")
connect_string = os.environ.get("PYTHON_CONNECTSTRING")

connection = cx_Oracle.connect(username, password, connect_string)

with connection.cursor() as cursor:

    # Predefine the memory areas to match the table definition
    cursor.setinputsizes(31,6,12,5)

    # Adjust the batch size to meet your memory and performance requirements
    batch_size = 10000

    with open('t.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
        sql = "insert into t (d, s, c, p) values (:1, :2, :3, :4)"
        data = []
        for line in csv_reader:
            data.append(line)
            if len(data) % batch_size == 0:
                cursor.executemany(sql, data)
                data = []
        if data:
            cursor.executemany(sql, data)
        connection.commit()

with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    sql = """select * from t"""
    for r in cursor.execute(sql):
        print(r)
```

the output is:

```
('16-JUN-21 08.00.00.000000000 PM', '00006', '+00000.0082', 'false')
```

For general reference see the cx_Oracle documentation [Batch Statement Execution and Bulk Loading](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/batch_statement.html).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I actually  found a very simple solution hahaha. Just do this instead: df = pd.read_csv(basepath,  sep=';', index_col = False, header=0, nrows=5,  dtype=str) when I read my df.